# Как отключить перенос строк в vscode для javascript и html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Правлю код vue.js компонента в vscode, при этом периодически жму Alt + Shift + F для автоматического форматирования введённого кода.

При этом постоянно меняется форматирование: код переносится на другую строку, хотя визуально места ещё очень много.

Пример.

Было:

[image: Before]

Стало (см. переносы свойств input'ов):

[image: After]

Можно ли это как-то настроить? В какую сторону копать настройки?

Comment: Так ведь легче читать, разве нет?

Comment: @meine это вопрос вкусов/привычки/кодстайла, не хочу об этом спорить.

Comment: Да никто и не собирается разводить спор, просто спросил :)

Comment: С расширением beautify для vsc такая же ситуация?

Comment: У меня из дополнительных расширений стоит только [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vetur использует **prettyhtml** для форматирования.

Посмотрите этот [документ](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/blob/master/docs/formatting.md)

---

**prettyhtml**

The default formatter for Vue templates.
Other settings include:

```
"vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
  "prettyhtml": {
    "printWidth": 100, // No line exceeds 100 characters
    "singleQuote": false // Prefer double quotes over single quotes
  }
}
```

prettier options are read from local .prettierrc config.

---

Вам следует поменять `printWidth`

Сначала следует убедиться, что HTML Formatter для Vetur таки prettyhtml: User Settings -> Extensions -> Vetur -> Format > Default Formatter: HTML

Если так, то попробуйте открыть settings.json: Ctrl-Shift-P, Open Settings (JSON) и добавить настройки здесь:

```
"vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": { "prettyhtml": {"printWidth": 300} }
```

Если там уже есть другие настройки, не забудьте запятую на предпоследней строке

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что `.prettierrc`  нужно создавать либо в папке проекта, либо в корне домашнего каталога? У меня что-то ни там ни там не срабатывает: при `"printWidth": 300` так и форматирует с переносом строки.

Comment: Я тоже так понимаю, но у меня не установлен prettyhtml, поэтому протестировать точно не могу. Я дополнил ответ, как внести нужную правку в настройки для пользователя.

Comment: Так и не завелось через `.prettierrc` хотя пробовал по-разному... А вот вариант через user settings сразу взлетел. Да, это именно та настройка, которую я искал, спасибо! Так что ещё на досуге попробую добить настройку через файл .prettierrc в папке проекта - а в целом решение подходит.

Answer (score 2):

Я данную проблему решил следующим образом: зашёл в Файл - Параметры - Параметры, там будет очень длинный список параметров редактора. В поисковой строке вводим  "Word Wrap Column", находим данный параметр. В поле данного параметра по умолчанию стоит цифра 80 - это и есть максимальное количество символов в строке, всё что длиннее - автоматически переносится в следующую строку. Стираем цифру 80 и пишем на пример 150 или 200 и вуаля - теперь автоперенос строк будет работать при количестве символов в строке 150 или 200 соответственно.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]