# Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь плагин для выравнивания HTML (и не только) кода в VS сode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь плагин для выравнивания HTML (и не только) кода в VS сode.

Comment: У VSCode "форматировать" код можно командой `Shift + Alt + F` на win и `Ctrl + Shift + I` на ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

[Из коробки идёт куча форматтеров, в том числе и для html](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html).

[Запускается](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/5752652) хоткеями:

- Shift + Alt + F (Format document)
- Ctrl+K Ctrl + F (Format selection)

И в принципе, этого вполне достаточно.

Если очень хочется чего-то очень продвинутого - поставьте [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode). К нему непросто привыкнуть, он  форматирует код так, как правильно, а не так как хочется вам и на первых порах будет жутко неудобно, непривычно и даже бесить. Но зато и выгод даёт немало: вы больше не будете руками форматировать документ и будете уверены, что все документы сделаны в едином стиле.

Comment: В едином отвратном стиле...

Comment: В prettier мне не понравилась его логика переноса длинных строчек кода. Все в такую кашу схлопывается. Например html, где я кое-где руками отформатировал, что бы было проще смотреть.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если не нравится логика переноса длинных строчек кода - [можно сделать длину строки подлиннее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/963971/213987). Я же в своё время решил посмотреть две недели на тот код, который получается после форматирования, не пытаясь исправить. Ну и привык, посмотрите в моих последних вопросах/ответах код весь уже через prettier пропущенный, заметно? Я у других стал видеть когда они юзают prettier. Это скорее вопрос привычки, не думаю, что prettier сделали "как изобрести ещё более отвратный стиль". Сложнее всего prettier подружить не с html, а под связку с линтером

Comment: @AK, а если сделать длиннее, то он наоборот все склеивает в 1 строку=( В итоге пользуюсь стандартным форматером, который мне лесенки и отступы делает.

Comment: @iluxa1810 жаль, что это не формат для so (сложно задать вопрос на субъективное восприятие) - может пройдём в какой-нибудь чатик и вы покажете пример некрасивого форматирования в prettier? Или может попробуете придумать? У вас пять сократов, возможно придумается серия вопросов на форматирование в prettier? С удовольствием почитаю и подискутирую.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вам аналогичное предложение ^^^ Пятница как раз. И где-то у нас даже был специализированный веб-чатик, наверняка замороженный - а у вас я знаю есть заклинание антифриз ;)