# Отключить автоматическое разбиение длинных строк при сохранении файла

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Недавно начал писать бота на *python* в *vscode* и возник такой вопрос.
При написании длинной команды *vscode* при сохранении разбивает её и переносит.

Как это убрать/отменить?

Как пример:

До

```
dispatcher.register_message_handler(next, lambda message: message.text == 'Следующий▶', state='*')
dispatcher.register_message_handler(previous, lambda message: message.text == '◀Предыдущий', state='*')
dispatcher.register_message_handler(main_menu, lambda message: message.text == 'Главное меню', state='*')
```

После

```
dispatcher.register_message_handler(
    next, lambda message: message.text == 'Следующий▶', state='*')
dispatcher.register_message_handler(
    previous, lambda message: message.text == '◀Предыдущий', state='*')
dispatcher.register_message_handler(
    main_menu, lambda message: message.text == 'Главное меню', state='*')
```

Если я правильно понял то это происходит из-за стандарта **pep8**(ограничение длинны строки). Мне нужно только это отключить, ну или расширить не затрагивая остальных элементов.

Comment: а зачем это убирать?

Comment: Дело привычки. Работаю на **С++** - у меня строки влево постоянно улетают; **C#, html, javascript** -тоже самое. А тут берёт и режет строки

Comment: Как вариант можете попробовать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963971/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-vscode-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-javascript-%D0%B8-html)

Comment: так там объяснение для prettyhtml, что мне не сильно подходит. Word Wrap Column - вообще без понятия для чего: там выставлял 1000 и не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полностью отключить форматирование при сохранении:

- Меню Файл -> Настройки -> Параметры (File -> Prefences -> Settings), в поиске вводите `format on save`, убираете галку в пункте "Editor: Format On Save";
- в файле settings.json это соответствует параметру `"editor.formatOnSave"` (нужно удалить этот параметр или заменить `true` на `false`)

Отключить автоперенос для длинных строк можно задав очень большое ограничение на длину строки (например, 1000 символов). Как конкретно - зависит от выбранного форматтера.

Какой форматтер у вас включен нужно смотреть там же в настройках в "Python > Formatting: Provider"

Для autopep8 (форматтер для Python по умолчанию) в настройках vscode ищите "Autopep8 Args", добавляете элемент `--max-line-length 1000` (см. [параметры командной строки autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8#:%7E:text=Options))

Comment: Хорошее решение, но не сильно подходит. При нормализации документа он все равно разбивает строку

Comment: @АлександрСамуськов дополнил ответ