# Форматирование строк в vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Добрый день при написании кода в Vs code и последующем сохранении строки вертикально ужимаются, как сделать так что бы строки вертикально не ужимались друг к другу ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отключить автоматическое разбиение длинных строк при сохранении файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467264/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Вкратце - отключить в настройках опцию "Format on save"