# Почему vs code ставит лишне вертикальные черты после сохранения pug

Tags: visual-studio-code

Что-то с настройками vs code, но не пойму, что именно. При кажом сохранении pug он добавляет это черточки, которые абсолютно не нужны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит включено автоматическое переформатирование файла при сохранении. Ну и видимо установленный плагин pug считает, что такие черточки дейститвельно нужны. Про отключение автоформатирования см. тут например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1467281/1365

Comment: Укажите какой форматтер для pug вы используете. Это нужно добавить в сам вопрос, нажав [edit] под вопросом